# enum and singletons - top level vs nested enum

Tags: java, enums, singleton

As is now well known the recommended way for creating a singleton in java is via an enum (see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689/what-is-an-efficient-way-to-implement-a-singleton-pattern-in-java))

But (for example in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2639896/281545)) it seems to be considered (by @MikeAdler who replied to me in the comments) the right thing to have the enum  ***in*** the singleton class (see for instance [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027701/singleton-using-enum) for a full example, or the code given below). I do not seem to really understand the need/use of this - can someone please elaborate (and preferably give the correct dialect for this idiom) ?

```
public class Enclosing {

    private  Enclosing() {}

    static enum Singleton {
        INSTANCE;

        private static final Enclosing  singleton = new Enclosing();

        public Enclosing getSingleton() {
            return singleton;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT : one would get the singleton by `Enclosing.Singleton.INSTANCE.getSingleton();`

Comment: That's if you want a singleton class, not a singleton enum.

Comment: @DaveNewton : could you elaborate in an answer ? I remind you that enums are special classes - and that the singleton will be an instance of some class anyway. What does it mean a "singleton class" ?

Comment: If you need, or have, a specific class, and you want it to be a singleton, this is one of the easiest ways to implement that. I don't really need to be reminded what an enum is, but thanks.

Comment: @DaveNewton Oh don't get me wrong :) Say I was reminding myself :D - still I do not really get the difference - why not create the class like this and not as a top level enum ?

Comment: I told you--if you already have, or for some reason specifically need, a given class, and you don't want an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would nest a Singleton when you wanted to perform [lazy-loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347961/singleton-lazy-loading-pattern) of it, say for testing reasons:

```
public class Singleton {
    public Enclosing getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    static enum SingletonHolder {
        INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Read more about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom

Comment: Makes sense - could you please elaborate on the mechanism ? As I see from your code the singleton would be created when the class `Singleton` is loaded for the first time while a top level enum would create the INSTANCE on application load ?

Comment: Why is this better than using a plain old enum ? As I don't think it is.

Comment: @Nim : cause the enum singleton is only created when/if needed (I guess - not sure how the class loader works)

Comment: Let's say SingletonHolder has static initialization that takes a long time.  If I want to call other static methods on Singleton without going through initialization I can.  This may be useful if I want to inject a different SingletonHolder INSTANCE for unit testing.

Comment: I don't see how static initializers are relevant. You can call static methods of enum without a new instance, and you can inject a different enum if you like. I don't get the advantage of your code at all.

Comment: An enum is lazy loaded anyway by the class loader.

Comment: @NimChimpsky : yes but it will be loaded as soon as any of its methods are called. Here you can call any of the static methods of `Singleton` and still not have the `SingletonHolder` initialized. Do read the linked wikipedia article (the How it works section) and please let me know if having objections. At Garrett Hall : I would appreciate some more concrete testing example - I do think I have to accept your answer though :)

Comment: A very very nice explanation of the "Initialization-on-demand holder idiom" aka [Lazy Initialization Holder Class by Josh Bloch](http://youtu.be/pi_I7oD_uGI?t=39m34s). I'd still appreciate some testing code, showing the need for this pattern :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public enum Foo {
   INSTANCE;
}
```

is the simplest and best way to get a singleton post-java 5. The code you posted is just  unnecessarily complex, I don't see any advantage of it over just using an enum.

Comment: Yes I know - iam wondering on the particular idiom of having this enum declared _nested_

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D it just looks messy to me.

Comment: It may but it is used and probably has some uses - that's why I am asking :)